# Sencha Touch ViewPort rendering issue onTap

Tags: list, sencha-touch, viewport, formpanel

I have a fully functional Sencha Touc 2.1.1 app bundled in Phonegap 2.5. In it, I have several lists that I use to spawn form panels for data entry and other sundry activities.

An example one is as follows (it happens on all my form panels that get opened via a list tap):

I have a list with an item template is rendered in this container:

```
Ext.define('EvaluateIt.view.Push', {
        extend: 'Ext.Container',
        fullscreen: true,
        //requires: ['Ext.TitleBar'],
        alias: 'widget.pushview',

        config: {
            layout: 'vbox',
            layout: 'fit',
            //id: 'pushview',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    docked: 'top',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            itemId: 'loginButton',
                            text: 'Login',
                            iconCls: 'arrow_right',
                            iconMask: true 
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            itemId: 'logOutButton',
                            text: 'Logout',
                            iconCls: 'arrow_right',
                            iconMask: true 
                        }

                    ]

                },
                {
                    flex: 1,
                    xtype: 'pushList'
                }

        ],
        listeners: [{
            delegate: '#logOutButton',
            event: 'tap',
            fn: 'onLogOutButtonTap'
        }]
    },
    onLogOutButtonTap: function () {
        this.fireEvent('onSignOffCommand');
    }

});
```

The list is:

```
Ext.define('EvaluateIt.view.PushList', {
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.List', //'Ext.tab.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.pushList',
    config: {
        width: Ext.os.deviceType == 'Phone' ? null : 300,
        height: Ext.os.deviceType == 'Phone' ? null : 500,
        xtype: 'list',
        store: 'SiteEvaluations', //getRange(0, 9),
        itemTpl: [
            '<div><strong>Address: {address}</strong></div> '
        ],
        variableHeights: false
    }

});
```

And the form that is opened on tapping an address rendered in the itemTpl is:

```
Ext.define('EvaluateIt.view.PushForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.pushForm',
    requires: [
        'Ext.form.Panel',
        'Ext.form.FieldSet',
        'Ext.field.Number',
        'Ext.field.DatePicker',
        'Ext.field.Select',
        'Ext.field.Hidden'
    ],
    config: {

    // We give it a left and top property to make it floating by default
        left: 0,
        top: 0,

        // Make it modal so you can click the mask to hide the overlay
        modal: true,
        hideOnMaskTap: true,

        // Set the width and height of the panel
        //width: 400,
        //height: 330,
        width: Ext.os.deviceType == 'Phone' ?  screen.width : 350,
        height: Ext.os.deviceType == 'Phone' ?  screen.height : 500,
        scrollable: true,
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox'
        },
        defaults: {
            margin: '0 0 5 0',
            labelWidth: '40%',
            labelWrap: true
        },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'textfield', 
                name: 'address',
                readOnly: true
            },
            /*{
                xtype: 'checkboxfield',
                id: 'addImage',
                label: 'Upload Image'
            },*/

            {
                xtype: 'button',
                itemId: 'save',
                text: 'Push to server'
            }

        ]
    }
});
```

This is called as a ViewPort via the following method in my controller:

```
onSelectPush: function(view, index, target, record, event) {

    console.log('Selected a SiteEvaluation from the list');
    var pushForm = Ext.Viewport.down('pushForm');

    if(!pushForm){
        pushForm = Ext.widget('pushForm');
    }    
    pushForm.setRecord(record);
    pushForm.showBy(target);

    console.log('Selected a Push from the list ' + index + ' ' + record.data.address);
}
```

This usually works as expected:

1. Open Push view
2. Tap on address in list
3. PushForm opens for user to do their thang.

However! Occasionally, when the user taps on the address, instead of the PushForm opening a black arrow shows up underneath the address in the list (see attached image)

[image].

It is unpredictable when this will happen, but it does. So far, its only happened on my Android device, not on an emulator or in a Web browser (I have not yet heard from any of my iOS users about this yet).

Note: The only way to get the app to function "normally" again is to either do a complete restart or a force close of the application.

Any ideas what is causing it? Grazie!!

Comment: Have you tried reducing the height and width of your push container? Just to see what happens..

Comment: Hi, I think had tried that a long time ago with no change in behavior. One thing that I found interesting while I was getting this to work, was that if I only use the layout: 'fit' without layout: 'vbox' in my container, all the records in my list do not get rendered. However, that had nothing to do with this issue. I am wondering if this is a device resource issue of some kind. Not being able to reproduce it on a Web browser though makes it tougher to figure out what the issue is.

Comment: No ideas? Anyone? Hmmm... maybe it is just happening on my device.